# Customer transaction e-mails only partly translated

Tags: magento-2.1, language

I have a language pack installed. That's giving my shop the language it needs. only when transactional mails are send out some parts are not translated. 
I decided to add them myself in a nl_NL.csv file. But unfortunately that's not applied. So How to deal with this and where to have the csv file loacated? I know I could change the templates as well, but that's taking a lot of time and the parts I need are general "subject" phrases.

Like these:

```
"Your %store_name order confirmation","Uw Bestelling van %store_name"
"Your %store_name order has shipped","Uw Bestelling is verstuurd %store_name"
"Invoice for your %store_name order","Uw Factuur von %store_name"
"Your Order <span class=""no-link"">#%increment_id</span>","Uw bestelling <span class=""no-link"">#%increment_id</span>"
```

This is where I have the csv file now:

[image]

This is what the mail looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by removing the language pack which was installed. And install an other better maintained language pack found through github.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep your translate csv file inside your theme root **i18n** folder.

**Currently You have placed csv file at wrong folder.**

Your csv file path,

**`app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/nl_NL.csv`** file.

You cant keep csv file inside your theme module folder.

Run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_NL
```

Clear cache and remove var folder.

Comment: I tried this but still not working. My mail looks like this now some parts are not translated.
have tried with the file in:
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/nl_NL.csv
app/code/i18n/nl_NL.csv

but not applied? Also run:
hp bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_NL and emptied the cache/ static.

Comment: Have you keep csv file inside root i18n folder

Comment: What do you mean by "root" in app/ or in /var/www/html/ ?

Comment: your theme root app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/i18n

Comment: I moved it from module into:    app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/i18n        
but that did not work.

Comment: Have you run deploy command and remove var folder from root.

Comment: well I run the deploy  command but did only emptie the cache in the admin. So I will try again with the var folder removed!

Comment: You have to run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_NL command

Comment: Yess I know and i'd run that. Now I have deleted the var dir and run the deply again with the file in: app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/i18n but te result is still the same ??

Comment: Although I do still not understand why my file is not used, I solved it by installing a better language pack :) now the mail subject and content seems to be the way I want. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please give proper answer of you given so others may useful and upvote answer.